# What kind of hash algorithm is used for Hive's built-in HASH() Function

Tags: hive, md5, hashcode, sha256

What kind of hashing algorithm is used in the built-in HASH() function?

I'm ideally looking for a SHA512/SHA256 hash, similar to what the SHA() function offers within the linkedin datafu UDFs for Pig.

Comment: You can tell a lot by the return type.  Since the HASH() function returns a (32-bit) INT type, you can safely assume it's not SHA512 or SHA256, since those would have 512-bit or 256-bit return types, respectively.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`HASH` function (as of Hive 0.11) uses algorithm similar to [java.util.List#hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode%28%29).

Its code looks like this:

```
int hashCode = 0; // Hive HASH uses 0 as the seed, List#hashCode uses 1. I don't know why.
for (Object item: items) {
   hashCode = hashCode * 31 + (item == null ? 0 : item.hashCode());
}
```

Basically it's a classic hash algorithm as recommended in the book Effective Java.
To quote a great man (and a great [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000WJOUPA)):

> The value 31 was chosen because it is an odd prime. If it were even
>   and the multiplication overflowed, information would be lost, as
>   multiplication by 2 is equivalent to shifting. The advantage of using
>   a prime is less clear, but it is traditional. A nice property of 31 is
>   that the multiplication can be replaced by a shift and a subtraction
>   for better performance: 31 * i == (i << 5) - i. Modern VMs do this
>   sort of optimization automatically.

I digress. You can look at the `HASH` source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop.hive/hive-exec/0.7.1-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFHash.java).

If you want to use SHAxxx in Hive then you can use Apache [DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) class and Hive built-in `reflect` function (I hope that'll work):

```
SELECT reflect('org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils', 'sha256Hex', 'your_string')
```

Comment: does it convert into string.. for given int type

Comment: I had a confuse about this; When terms had only two elements, and all the element is equals, in this case HashCode = (0 * 31 +  eleRawHash ) * 31 + eleRawHash => 32 * eleRawHash =>  eleRawHash << 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

As of [Hive 2.1.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13568) there is a `mask_hash` function that will hash string values.

For Hive 2.x it uses md5 as the hashing algorithm. This was [changed to sha256](https://github.com/apache/hive/commit/3c6d4cb5ddb241a2fca96e70b15ef83cd31d0a31) for Hive 3.x