# Calculate hash without using exisiting hash fuction in Hive

Tags: hive

I want to calculate hash for strings in hive without writing any UDF only using exisiting functions . So that I can use similar approach to get consistent hash in other languages. for ex : are there any functions using which I can do something like adding characters or taking Xor.

Comment: Your title says *"without using exisiting hash fuction"* but your question says *"only using exisiting functions"* which is the exact opposite. What do you want, actually??

Comment: You'll have to be more specific regarding the Hive version you are using and the other languages you are referring to

Comment: "So that I can use similar approach to get consistent hash in other languages" So If I use existing hash function it wont be similar if I calculate it in some other language . So I want to calculate simplest hash possible using "other" existing functions which I will be able to replicate in other languages also. For Ex :I want to bucketize strings so I can do ASCII("abc")%NoofBuckets it will give me ascii of first character , but distribution across buckets wont be that good . So I need something which is more reasonable that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of Hive, cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Misc.Functions

`select XYZ, hash(XYZ) from ABC`
has been available for years and applies plain old `java.lang.String.hashCode()`, returning an INT (32 bit hash)

*[Edit 2] Actually it's a bit more complex since `hash()` accepts a list of arguments of any type (incl. primitive types that have no built-in hashing method), so a custom approach is used -- check `ObjectInspectorUtils.hashCode()` and `ObjectInspectorUtils.getBucketHashCode()` in the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-2.1/serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/objectinspector/ObjectInspectorUtils.java) (for V2.1)*

`select XYZ, crc32(XYZ) from ABC`
requires Hive 1.3 and applies plain old Cyclic Redundancy Check (probably via `java.util.zip.CRC32`), returning a BIGINT (32 bit hash)

`select XYZ, md5(XYZ), sha1(XYZ), sha2(XYZ,256), sha2(XYZ,512) from ABC`
requires Hive 1.3 and applies strong, *cryptographic* hash functions, returning a STRING with the hexadecimal representation of the binary (128, 160, 256 and 512 bit hashes)

*[Edit 1]* the answer to [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176602/what-kind-of-hash-algorithim-is-used-for-hives-built-in-hash-function) has also a very good workaround for applying crypto hash functions with older versions of Hive, using Apache Commons static methods and `reflect()`.