# Is hash function in hive one way hash?

Tags: hive

I am looking for a one-way hash in hive.
Seems like there is already a [hash](https://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/hive-functions) function - hash(a1[, a2...])

What kind of hash function is this? Is this a one-way hash?

Comment: Can you cite a hashing algorithm that is not, by definition, a one-way function? Cf. Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function (especially the illustration of a _collision_ on the upper right)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138612/calculate-hash-without-using-exisiting-hash-fuction-in-hive