# How does the built-in Apache Hive hash function work and where can I find that documentation?

Tags: hash, hive, mapreduce

I'm working with Apache Hive and need to be certain of how the built-in hash function works. I found [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inFunctions) page that lists `hash` under the **Misc. Functions** section. It says that `hash` has been available "As of Hive 0.4".

I would just like to see some documentation on what it's doing exactly. Is it deterministic? Will it always produce the same output given the same input? How many collisions should I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hash function is deterministic, by definition, cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Determinism
So if the implementation of `hash()` was not deterministic, then it would be a bug, and someone would have noticed!

*Caveat: that implementation is subject to change (and bug fixes) hence determinism stands only for a given version of Hive.*

---

Hive is Open Source. Documentation is not bad by Apache standards, but still incomplete. Just inspect the source code => https://github.com/apache/hive

For Hive 2.1 for example:

- the `hash()` function *(an UDF in Hive jargon)* is defined [here](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-2.1/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFHash.java)
- it just calls `ObjectInspectorUtils.getBucketHashCode()` which calls `ObjectInspectorUtils.hashCode()` on each argument, then merges its hash into a global "bucket" hash - as defined [here](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-2.1/serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/objectinspector/ObjectInspectorUtils.java)
- a comment shows that the (crude) hashing method implemented by Hive is derived from `String.hashCode()`

---

For alternative hashing functions in Hive, see [Calculate hash without using exisiting hash fuction in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138612/calculate-hash-without-using-exisiting-hash-fuction-in-hive) but the answer basically points to the same documentation page that you already found.