# Consistent Hive and Impala Hash?

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I am looking for a consistent way to hash something in both the Hive Query Language and the Impala Query Language where the hashing function produce the same value regardless of if it is done in Hive or in Impala. To clarify, I want something like `some_hive_hash_thing(A) = some_other_impala_hash_thing(A)`.

For Hive, I know there is `hash()` which uses MD5 (or any of the commands [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Misc.Functions)).
For Impala, I know there is `fnv_hash()` which uses the FNV algorithm. I know that Hive and Impala have their own hashing functions, but they are completely different from one another.

Ideally, I am looking for a way to do `fnv_hash` in Hive, or a way to do MD5 in Impala. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: _"Hive `hash()` returns a 32-bit int and uses MD5"_ > this is **nonsense**; read the Wikipedia page about MD5 (spoiler: it is a **128-bit** cryptographic hash -- flawed from a crypto perspective, but still way more reliable than crude 32-bit things)

Comment: Hive has a number of hashing functions available -- from crude 32-bit things that are dangerous when used in a "Big Data" context where the probability of collision becomes significant simply because of the number of records (`hash` cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21184449/5162372 or `crc32`) to crypto hash functions `md5` (128-bit, flawed) `sha1` (160-bit) `sha2` (224 to 512-bit options). Except that you use Impala, hence you use Cloudera, hence you are blocked to an obsolete version of Hive, hence you may not even have the crypto hash functions available.

Comment: The MD5 thing was strange to me too, I must have misinterpreted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138612/calculate-hash-without-using-exisiting-hash-fuction-in-hive.  I tried to look in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Misc.Functions and saw the large number of options available. None of them seemed similar to what I might be able to do in Impala, however.

Comment: The funny thing is that Impala uses multiple kinds of hash functions internally http://impala.io/doc/html/classimpala_1_1HashUtil.html and may use more in the future https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-2277 but exposes only FNV-1a to use in SQL. You could try to create a Hive UDF by using some Java code available on GitHub -- but make sure you use the same "primes" as in the Impala C++ implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so late as an answer, but let's keep it here for someone else who may find it helpful.

"A way to do MD5 in Impala" yes there is and you can use UDFs built-in function of Hive in Impala in the recent releases (I'm using CDH 5.12 and it's working well with impala 2.9, and hive 1.1)

you can find here the list of the built-in functions 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

or you can simply run 
`SHOW FUNCTIONS;` 
in your hive console 
`beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000`

so let's do a simulation of adding the MD5 function from hive to Impala.

```
DESCRIBE FUNCTION md5;
```

To make sure the function exists and to know the input and output variables type, so here we know that md5(string) takes a string as variable and a string as a return type .

Next we need to find hive-exec jar that contains our MD5 class using the Jar command :

```
/opt/jdk**/bin/jar tf hive-exec-*.*.*-cdh**.jar | grep Md5
```

Jar command is usually in the /bin under your java repository if it's not already configured in your environment variables .

you can find hive-exec-X-X.jar file  in ../lib/hive/lib/ , if you can't find it just use locate command

so the output is something like :

```
 /opt/jdk**/bin/jar tf hive-exec-*.*.*-cdh**.jar | grep Md5
   org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFMd5.class
```

save that path for later but we'll replace the '/' by '.' and remove the '.class'
like this : 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFMd5

copy the jar file in a directory accessible by HDFS and you may rename it for a simple use 'Im gonna name it hive-exec.jar'.

```
cp /lib/hive/lib/hive-exec.jar  /opt/examples/

chown -R hdfs /opt/examples/
```

then create a place to put your jars in hdfs

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /user/hive/warehouse/hive_jars
```

Copy your jar file to HDFS using :

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /opt/examples/hive-exec.jar /user/hive/warehouse/hive_jars/
```

so now you just have to go to Impala-shell and connect to a database then create your function using your HDFS path to the jar and the .class path we agreed earlier to convert in symbol.

```
   Impala-shell>use udfs;
 create function to_md5(string) returns string location '/user/hive/warehouse/hive_jars/hive-exec.jar' symbol='org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFMd5';
```

here you go you can use it now like any Impala function  :

```
select to_md5('test');
    | udfs.to_md5('test')             |
    +----------------------------------+
    | 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 |

    show functions ;
    Query: show functions
    +-------------+----------------------+-------------+---------------+
    | return type | signature            | binary type | is persistent |
    +-------------+----------------------+-------------+---------------+
    | STRING      | to_md5(STRING)       | JAVA        | false         |
```

Comment: GenericUDFs are not supported in Impala yet.

exameple :org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.GenericUDFSha2